# How can I access the standard output and standard error of a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, io, pry

I have a method that takes input and outputs text to the console.

To be more specific my code looks similar to this:

```
require 'pry'

p = Pry.new
p.eval("some Ruby code in string form to be evaluated that prints to the console")
```

I'm trying to capture this output. If I assign the `eval` line to a variable, it just comes back as `true` no matter what, whereas it will print the appropriate evaluated response to the code to my console.

I've looked at and tried several approaches I found here on SO, some of them using `Open3` and some using `STDOUT` and `$stdout`. Each time I try something I get Errno errors or IO errors, and I've been following the documentation as closely as possible. Not sure where to turn. Also I'm new to IO concepts, which hasn't been helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
require 'stringio'

$stdout = StringIO.new

eval 'Some code here bla bla bla'

output = $stdout.string
$stdout = STDOUT

# `output` is now the stdout of the command
```

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much. Would you happen to know where I can learn more about IO in general and in Ruby? All of the references I've found get super technical really fast. Especially the documentation. Cheers